# Flexslider won't scroll in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed, flexslider

I have an issue where the `flexslider` stays static in IE7. All other browsers it's fine.

```
<div class="flexslider">
   <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="images/banners/design-227.jpg"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

It appears to be the flexviewport `div` that is stuck. I can't see anywhere where the CSS is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a js error:

SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number slider.options.js?m62tl1, line 35 character 5

In the line 'slideToStart: 0,':

```
$('article.flexible-slideshow .flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "fade",
      slideshowSpeed: 6000,
      slideToStart: 0,
    });
```

I removed the last comma, and everything started to work normally.

Try looking at the IE console, pay attention at the errors. Remove every comma before  `})`;